# How do I validate a jQuery datepicker field using the Rails client_side_validations gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

I'm trying to get a jQuery datepicker instance to validate with client_side_validations and not having any luck.

Anytime I include this in my model

```
validates_presence_of :due_date, :message => "Please select the due date"
```

The form just doesn't submit - no JS error, no log entry from Rails.

When I remove focus from the field without a value I do get the error message, so I know it's working at least a little bit.

Just can't figure out how to get the form submitting.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including the csrf token in your submission?

Comment: Yes, it's in there, but it's not even getting to the point of making a POST request.  Just doesn't make it that far.

Comment: Ah my bad. I understand now. If it is the case that you have no submission happening at all, then you should be able to debug entirely in JS. Are you sure you checked, for example, the JS console in chrome to see what is going on when you try to submit? I'd don't have much experience debugging JS or I would give more specific ideas.

Comment: Yeah, I've got nothing in the console.  Strange I know.  Thanks for the consideration anyway.

Comment: So... when you don't have that in your model, it works. When you do have it in your model, the submission stops working? If so, then the offending code would seem to be somewhere in the client_side_validations gem that I assume is converting your validations into javascript. Can you dig into that to find out where it handles validates_presence_of ?

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/master/lib/client_side_validations/active_model/presence.rb) I think... Not sure what you can do with that though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me CSV is hijacking the form before POST, because it doesn't pass, which makes sense. Do you have a :validate => true on the field itself, and are you using callbacks to generate a message? Because without them, it seems CSV will just reject the POST silently. Also, thinking about it, I've had a similar problem with select boxes and CSV, where no "field_with_errors" can be generated. Also, it's possible that the datepicker JS is conflicting with CSV.